# subclass Objective-C Class in Swift and Override init function/method

Tags: swift

I tried to inherit a swift class from WebView (Objective-C) and tried to override the init method. But I get a very strange Error. (Xcode 6.1)

```
WebViewController.swift: 12: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:frameName:groupName:)' for class 'Project.WebViewController'
```

That's my class:

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

class WebViewController : WebView     // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
{
    override init!() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)) 
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is WebView? Did you mean WKWebView?

Comment: `WebView` is the OS X version of `UIWebView`.